# Stronger than contraction mapping

Tags: functions

I'd like to know how to find a function for which
$|f(a) - f(b)| < C * |a - b|^p$ where $C\in (0;1)$ (for p = 1 it's a contraction mapping, I am looking for functions for which p > 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a function is continuous ($f(a) \to f(b)$ as $a \to b$, clearly), and also differentiable, with derivative zero:
$$ \left\lvert \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} \right\rvert \leqslant C \lvert h \rvert^{p-1} \to 0 $$
as $h \to 0$. Since this is true for any $a$, we must have $f'(a) \equiv 0 $. By the Mean Value Theorem, only constant functions can do this, so $f$ must be constant.